# How to fix StaleObjectStateException with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, staleobjectstate

Controller Logic:

```
def updateObject() {

    Object o = Object.get(params.id as Long)

    o.otherObjects.clear()

    objectDataService.saveObject(o.id)

    OtherObject newObject = new OtherObject;

    o.addToOtherObjects(newObject)

    objectDataService.saveObject(o.id)

}
```

ServiceLogic

```
def saveObject(long profileId) {
    o.save(flush:true)
}
```

**what happens**

in 90% of the cases this will just work.

**problems**

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - StaleObjectStateException occurred when processing request: [GET] /controller/updateObject - parameters:
stuff[]: data
Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.path.Object#1]. 
Stacktrace follows:
Message: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.path.Object#1]
```

i have read through related questions and found the `merge` call you see above. it solved about 50% of the cases but not all.

Comment: wouldn't you be better off here if you moved this logic into a service method so it was all done under the same transaction?

Comment: i dont want to overload the service. do you think it would make sense?

Comment: It's always better to move the business logic to services and make your controllers as thin as possible (By thin I mean with fewer lines of code). This will help you in reusing the code wherever required and save a lot of time in testing as well.

Comment: Are you expecting concurrent requests on this action by many users or just one user is hitting the action more than once?

Comment: @NikhilBhandari it is currently just myself testing. no concurrent users at all (all on localhost)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For us a few different approaches finally solved the StaleObjectException from occuring regularly:

```
object = object.refresh()
```

refreshing objects after retrieving them solved most of our StaleObjectExceptions. Especially in cases where there was a possibility that someone would have worked on the same object from somewhere else and changed some of its members (most problems arrived with collection members).

Overall Project stability:

```
wrongly linked resources
```

we had a 404 on a specific resource file we did not actually need and therefore ignored it for some time. turns out that the missing file would cause the session to be kept open - thus fabricating StaleObjects left and right.

Therefore as a hint to anyone facing **more than the usual** (some StaleObjects might always occur - see above answers) StaleObjectExceptions: Make sure that **all** resources are linked correctly and your developer tools (Chrome F12) do not report any missing files.

Answer (score 12):

**StaleObjectStateException:**

> As already commented out about this exception. 
>   When an invalid version-ed domain object is in the session during a flush (explicit or implicit) the version number is bumped but it is not persisted to the database. Then, when it becomes valid again and saved and flushed, hibernate considers it stale, since the version number does not match the version in the database and it throws a 
>   StaleObjectStateException.

This can be solve like.

> 1. you have to find out version value before doing the update , if it's 1 then you have to update by using program. at particular operation of update .
> 2. By using @version annotation.

About @version:

> The version number mechanism for optimistic locking is provided through a @Version annotation.
>   Example: The @Version annotation

```
@Entity
public class Flight implements Serializable {
...
    @Version
    @Column(name="OPTLOCK")
    public Integer getVersion() { ... }
}
```

Here, the version property is mapped to the OPTLOCK column, and the entity manager uses it to detect conflicting updates, and prevent the loss of updates that would be overwritten by a last-commit-wins strategy [@version](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html)

For more detail on Grails refer below link , it's having Git hub code.
[test for GRAILS-8937: HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/commit/983d6676c469fc2335f9cfa4c9d47504b2789883)

Comment: could you elaborate on your solutions? how would i use the @version annotation and what would i update in 1the first solution?

Comment: @SebastianFlückiger : those are the approach to solve that exception,check more detail about hibernate framework to understand version usage.I updated some detail as well about version.Other given link tells on Grails related solution.1st solution to read version no. from table and then update that version by writing code.

Answer (score 7):

The [StaleObjectStateException](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/StaleObjectStateException.html) can occur naturally on any other project. Every time two concurrent transactions are loading the same entity version and each of those change that entity you end up with the last executing thread failing, due to an optimistic locking collision failure.

In your case there is an extra call, outside of JPA boundaries, that may facilitate this issue:

```
Object o = PObject.lock(profileId)
```

Each transaction is thread-bound and it happens inside a Session, so two competing threads will keep two Object references for the same entity id. The optimistic locking goal works effectively without any other explicit locking mechanism.

If you send the modified entity reference to the `saveObject` version and you still get this exception, it means you have a high chance for two competing threads to modify the same entities.

In this scenario, a [pessimistic lock](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-java-persistence-locking/) will yield better results, since it involves waiting as opposed to the [optimistic fail-fast approach](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-database-locking-and-the-lost-update-phenomena/).

Comment: i updated my code. the .lock() call is not in there anymore. i still have the occurence around 20% times of the calls. it is not concurrent ( i am fabricating it alone as single user so no concurrent edits )